# ElasticSearch 7.1 Delete Index C# API

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am updating my project to use ES & NEST v7.1 from v6.8 and I would like to know the counterpart of IndicesDeleteAsync API.

```
Task<TResponse> IndicesDeleteAsync<TResponse>(string index, DeleteIndexRequestParameters requestParameters = null, CancellationToken ctx = default(CancellationToken)) where TResponse : class, IElasticsearchResponse, new();
```

There is a function to delete an index in lowLevelClient in 7.1 but it takes `id` parameter and deletes a document.

```
Task<TResponse> DeleteAsync<TResponse>(string index, string id, DeleteRequestParameters requestParameters = null, CancellationToken ctx = default(CancellationToken)) where TResponse : class, IElasticsearchResponse, new();
```

I don't want to delete a document in an index, I want to delete the entire index.

How can I perform this task in v7.x ?

Comment: Try Indices.DeleteAsync

Comment: Oh! Great. I totally Overlooked LowLevelIndicesNamespace class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create and deleted methods have been moved to Indices namespace

var response=elasticClient.Indices.DeleteAsync("indexname");

See "Namespaced API methods and Upgrade Assistant" in (elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/7.0.0)[https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/7.0.0] for help with upgrading.